How to lift state in React when there's no common parent
The concept of lifting state from one component to a common parent is straight forward. However I need to lift state for components that have no shared parent. Obviously, I'll need to create that parent component, but how is this set up especially since the child components would never be rendered together? Where does the parent get called and how does it communicate with its child components? Can someone point me to a clear example?

All components will have a shared parent at some point unless the components are in separate projects or mounted into separate HTML elements via ReactDOM. Can you clarify how your two components do not share a parent?

They may not share an immediate parent, but I don't see how they wouldn't share a parent somewhere in the hierarchy.  If you're looking for options which don't involve passing props down through multiple components then perhaps you're looking for something like useContext or Redux or a custom hook?

Maybe the misunderstanding here is that a parent component that you can lift state up to must be a component's immediate parent. In reality, it can be any component higher up in the tree that ultimately renders both components. If that's the case, you may just have to lift state up more than one level. If there's several levels you'd have to lift through, that's when context, redux, custom hook become a great tool

Share a [example] that shows your current idea.

In cases like this you might want to use a context where you have your state stored in a parent component at the top level in the hierarchy and it's called a Provider. then you can retrieve this state using hooks.
You can use the React context (There are also other alternatives but they share the same idea, like Redux store)
React Context:

you create a Provider component like this:

import { createContext } from "react"

export const ThemeContext = createContext('light');

export function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
  // ...
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
      <Page />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}


You can use you stored state inside any component that is wrapped by this Provider

import { useContext } from "react"

export function Component() {
 const theme = useContext(ThemeContext) // you might want to create a custom hook for that too

 return <div>{theme}</div>
}

Redux
// store.ts
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import themeReducer from './slices/themeSlice'

export const store =  configureStore({
  reducer: {
    theme: themeReducer
  }
})

// themeSlice.ts
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const themeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'theme',
  initialState: {
    value: "light"
  },
  reducers: {
    toggle: state => {
        state.value = state.value === "light" ? "dark" : "light"
    }
  }
})

export const {toggle: toggleTheme} = themeSlice.actions

export default themeSlice.reducer

// Top level
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {store} form "../redux/store"

export function App() {

  return <Provider store={store}>
    <Component />
  </Provider>
}

// Component
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTheme } from '../redux/slices/themeSlice'

export function Component() {
  const theme = useSelector(state => state.theme.value)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return <div>{theme}<button onClick={() => dispatch(toggleTheme())}>toggle</button></div>
}

Check these links for more details:

Create context
Use context
Redux


You need to post code in the answer to solve the issue. We don't allow link-only answers.

Is the answer ok now ?

Much better! +1
